# I want to change my dexie values which are null to empty strings

Tags: javascript, database, datatable, dexie

I want to change my data-tables values which are null to empty strings.

Sometimes the department value will be empty, in which case it will put null in my data tables.

```js
db = db_open();

db.fuel.toArray().then(fuel => {
  fuel.forEach(function(fuel) { 
    $('#table_bod').append('<tr> <td>'+fuel.department+'</td> </tr> ');
  })
});
```

I tried:

```js
const fuels = db.fuel.where({department: null});
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedDB cannot match against null so in order to find those you must do a full table scan.

```
const fuelsWithoutDepartment = await db.fuel
  .filter(x => x.department === null)
  .toArray();
```

Create an upgrader that modifies all null departments to empty string in case you want to have that instead of null.

```
db.version(2).stores({
  fuel: 'id, department'
}).upgrade (tx => {
  return tx.fuel.filter(
    x => x.department === null
  ).modify({department: ""});
});
```

Once you've declared such an upgrader (please adjust it to the appropriate version, id and indexes for your case), then you won't need a full table scan to find fuels without departments anymore but can use the department index (if you have one):

```
const fuelsWithoutDepartment = await db.fuel
  .where({department: ""})
  .toArray();
```

Comment: i find this very useful for when adding new data directly to dexieDB instead from MySQL, so that when data is added my ** now declared updater makes sure i don't have null in my dexie database** . Thanks for that